# UnicodeDecodeError from Tensorflow Tutorials "Text classification with TF Hub"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just start learning tensorflow with Tutorials of Tensorflow Core.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_data, validation_data, test_data = tfds.load(name='imdb_reviews', split=('train[:60%]', 'train[60%:]', 'test'), as_supervised=True)
```

then I got error like this.

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxoyA.png)

Some blog says this Error can be resolved by installing tensorflow-gpu.
But in my case, that dosen't work.

How can I fix this error?
(win10, anaconda. conda ver. 4.9.2., windows terminal, anaconda prompt)

Comment: I was able to execute above code without any issues. Can you try to reinstall tensorflow and let us know?

Comment: Thank you. I have re-installed anaconda and etc.. so now I can run above code. Thank you again. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-installation of Anaconda and Tensorflow issue was resolved.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_data, validation_data, test_data = tfds.load(name='imdb_reviews', split=('train[:60%]', 'train[60%:]', 'test'), as_supervised=True)
```